how to read a db.properties file or any other conf file in the project when deployed
how to read a db.properties file or any other conf file in the project when deployed in production?
i m getting this error...
24/05/09 16:34:32 INFO Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1715046519048_2131/container_e37_1715046519048_2131_02_000001/user/db.properties does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:930)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:631)

first i kept in my local it didnt worked then i kept in hdfs directory
here is my code for scala:-
sparkContext.addFile("hdfs://user/db.properties")
val propertiesFile = SparkFiles.get("hdfs://user/db.properties")
val properties = new Properties()
properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFile))

and here is the script i m using for running the spark application. i have neccessary details in my script but here is the for the files one.
[spark-submit.sh]

 --files hdfs://user/db.properties \

and also i kept my db.properties outside src folder lke this:-
project-root/
├── db.properties
│   
│   
│   
└── src/
    └── main/
        └── scala/
            └── mysqlTohive.scala

and in production i kept file like this in different path:
-
path-home/user/spark/    [where below files are there]
-->mysqlTohive.scala
-->db.properties


Aren't you missing an extra / : hdfs:///user.... Otherwise it looks in relative directory rather than root directory.

still getting same error ...used with extra /  [ "hdfs:///user/db.properties" ] and also in my script.sh like this --files hdfs:///user/db.properties \

Per your last edit, the file is actually under /user/spark?

yes in my hdfs it is inside this /user/db.properties and in my production where my jar and files is there it is inside this path home/user/spark/

It sounds like the file actually isn't where you are telling the program to look. I would use try to bin/hdfs dfs -ls  <path> to explore the path, if you have access to the HDFS utilities, for example, if you can SSH into the cluster. Otherwise, you can try to list files from the Spark program:
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://"))

If you are actually not keeping a copy of the file in HDFS, but it is locally available where the spark-submit is performed (e.g. actually bootstrapped onto a driver node in a cluster), then you may be able to simply use a local, absolute or relative, path (i.e. without the hdfs:// prefix)
properties.load(new java.io.FileInputStream(SparkFiles.get("db.properties"))) // or /path-home/user/spark/ etc.


i also tried with this .....not working...........val properties = new Properties()
val propertiesFile = new FileInputStream("db.properties")
properties.load(propertiesFile)
propertiesFile.close()
